# Original publication of P.A.M. Dirac

Tags: reference-request, spin-geometry

For an article I am looking for the *original publication* of P.A.M. Dirac where he explained the difference between a $2\pi$ and $4\pi$ rotation by using a model with strings.
This is sometimes called orientation entanglement or the Dirac belt trick.